# cpp graphical menu

Tags: c++, class, object

I am making a new graphical menu interface for a project I am making. I don't want to use the menu system provided by windows APIs and want to make one from scratch.

My question is, what is the best method for setting up the structure?

I'm thinking I will need a menu item object, each of which will have to have their own item array list, etc...

Is it considered sloppy to have recursive coding like that? (Ie an object which contains objects of itself, which contains objects of itself, etc...)

I'm thinking I can give the item object a draw interface which checks itself to see if it has an item array that is not null. If it does, it executes the draw command all the way down, thereby giving me a menu with (for my purposes) unlimited submenu level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion your approach is fine. In nearly all UI frameworks, views contain views as subviews after all.

But the thing is that writing drawing code is too much work for small projects I think. I would consider using a UI framework such as QT and use its view mechanism as a starting point. You can write your own Menu class which will be a subclass of generic View class in the framework.

Comment: With Qt you either need to open source your application or own a preposterously expenssive commercial license to statically link only what you need, with LGPL you will have to bundle 10-15MB worth of DLLs - at least QtCore and QtGui, even if all you need is a few push buttons. There are lighter libraries out there that allow static linking.

Comment: You are right, Qt was just an example that came into my mind in the first place.

Comment: I've looked at Qt a little bit.  I have seen a lot of linux programmers reccommend it.  I still have not read enough to know or understand any Linux OS API's, including KDE, GNOME, etc....